# ModalPopupExtender inside DataList show up onclick of ImageButton inside datalist item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist filled with items from database and each item has an image button onclick of which I want to show a modalpopup containing the Description of the particular Item. Below is what I have dine so far but fail:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">

    <ItemTemplate>
    <table width="228px">
    <tr>
    <td width="20px" >&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="160px" align="center">
    <asp:Label ID="pID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#336699" Width="100%" />
    </td>
    <td align="right">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="SpecificBtn" ImageUrl="images/SmallCallout.png"  OnClick="SpecificBtn_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdl" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnl" TargetControlID="SpecificBtn" Enabled="True" CancelControlID="btn" DropShadow="true" Drag="True"  ></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>    
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.aspx?id=" + Eval("id") %>' /><br />
    <table align="center" style="position:relative; left:2px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0" width="228px">
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:Black;" colspan=2>
    <div >
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="/images/cart.png" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button CommandName="AddToCart" CssClass="anchor" OnClick="addProduct" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ID="addToHire" runat="server" Text="        Add To Cart      " BackColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#F8CD20" Height="24" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="10" />
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="dataListItemStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"  />
    </asp:DataList>



<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" visible="false" Width="300px" Height="300px"   BackColor="red">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Specification"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Specification") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="cancel" /> 
    </asp:Panel>
```

Code behind:

```
        protected void SpecificBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataListItem dli = (DataListItem)((ImageButton)sender).Parent;
        ModalPopupExtender ModalPopupExtender2 = (ModalPopupExtender)dli.FindControl("mdl");
        pnl.Visible = true;
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();

    }
```

Can somebody tell me how to acheive this and where I went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery..

```
    function onimagebuttonclick()
     {
        $find('BehaviorIDofmodelpopupextender').show();
     }
```

i hope this solves your problem..